# React.js className value with string interpolation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm expressing a `jsx` template in the following way:

```
// looping here
<li key={some_key} className={props.location.pathname.includes(path) && 'active'}>
<NavLink to={path}>{path.name}</NavLink>
// end loop
```

It works fine but in dev mode I'm seeing a lot of warnings about how the non-active `li` items have empty `className` properties, which it doesn't like. I tried doing:

```
<li key={some_key} {props.location.pathname.includes(path.path) ? 'className="active"' : ''}>
```

but that fails to compile.

Is there a way to do this so the `className` doesn't get written if it's empty, or possibly the `NavLink` can take a parent prop or something that it will also set to active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use string interpolation as follows :

```
 <li key={some_key} className={`${props.location.pathname.includes(path)?'active':''}`}>
```